# How to print a wordpress post tag into html class

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Hi everyone I am trying to print out wordpress tag into html class, code looks like this

```
<div id="space-above" class="mix /* Print Tag Here */ col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
```

To get something like this

```
<div id="space-above" class="mix g col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
```

I tryed using  `get_the_tags();`  but had no luck so far.

Here is whole code I have in content.php

```
<div id="space-above" class="mix col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
  <a class="cast-shadow" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
    <div class="card-wraper">
      <img src="#" alt=""/>
      <div class="card-text">
        <?php the_title( '<h2 class="card-title"><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h2>' ); ?>
        <?php the_content( '<p class="card-description"><a class="card-text-link" href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></p>' ); ?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to do this inside the [loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop)?

Comment: Try this:

$posttags = get_the_tags();
$tags = []
if ($posttags) {
    foreach($posttags as $tag) {
        $tags[] = $tag->name;
    }
}
$tagsAsString = implode(' ', $tags);

<div id="space-above" class="mix <?php echo $tagsAsString ?> col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">

Comment: @Und3rTow It's not a loop, I edited the post to include whole code that I have in content.php

Comment: `content.php` is technically inside the loop, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get_the_tags` returns an array, so something like this should work:

```
<div id="space-above" class="mix <?php foreach( get_the_tags() as $tag ) { echo $tag->name.' ';}; ?> col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
```

Comment: It give's me this

    <div id="space-above" class="mix <br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\arielpalc\wp-content\themes\arielpalc\content.php</b> on line <b>1</b><br />
 col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">

Comment: Is this a post or a page?

Comment: It's a post, I am trying to set up content.php

Comment: Ok, I tested this on a post, and it works as expected. Are you sure you have added tags to the post? https://imgur.com/a/T7iFt

Comment: I added them, but didn't update pages, now this works perfectly.

Comment: ahh... nice one :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you want. You can get the tags first, then add them using jQuery. Have a try

```
 <div id="space-above" class="mix col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
  <a class="cast-shadow" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
    <div class="card-wraper">
      <img src="#" alt=""/>
      <div class="card-text">
        <?php the_title( '<h2 class="card-title"><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h2>' ); ?>
        <?php the_content( '<p class="card-description"><a class="card-text-link" href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></p>' ); ?>

         <?  $t = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);
            $htm = '';
            foreach ($t as $tg) {
                $htm .= $tg." ";
            }
            ?>
    </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
        var classes = "<?php echo $htm; ?>"
        jQuery('.mix').addClass(classes)
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: It didn't work for me, I edited the post to include whole code, maybe I didn't applied it right.

Comment: No, still don't work, it just adds that php code as a plain text, and when I try to add php before opening <? it just disappears without doing anything.

Comment: can you get the tags? in PHP only?